# Setters don't get called when I use view parameters

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.1.1. I have a sample JSF page that is used to post country comments. I use the `f:viewparam` tag to select country pages. Here is the code:

`country.xhtml`:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="country" value="#{countryBean2.selectedCountry}" converter="countryConverter" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <title>Country</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:outputText value="#{countryBean2.selectedCountry.countryName}" />
            <br/><br/>
            <h:outputText value="Comment:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{countryBean2.comment}" />
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Send">
                <f:ajax  listener="#{countryBean2.sendComment}" render="form" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

`CountryBean2.java`:

```
@Named("countryBean2")
@SessionScoped
public class CountryBean2 implements Serializable {
    private EntityCountry selectedCountry;
    private String comment;

    public EntityCountry getSelectedCountry() { return selectedCountry; }
    public void setSelectedCountry(EntityCountry newValue) { selectedCountry = newValue; }

    public String getComment() { return comment; }
    public void setComment(String newValue) { comment = newValue; }

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");

    public void sendComment() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            FacesMessage msg = null;
            EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
            boolean committed = false;
            entr.begin();
            try {
                EntityCountryComment c = new EntityCountryComment();
                c.setCountry(selectedCountry);
                c.setComment(comment);
                em.persist(c);
                committed = true;
                msg = new FacesMessage();
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
                msg.setSummary("Comment was sended");
            } finally {
                if (!committed) entr.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

`CountryConverter.java`:

```
public class CountryConverter implements Converter {
    public static EntityCountry country = new EntityCountry();

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");


    @Override
    public EntityCountry getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM EntityCountry c WHERE c.countryName = :countryName")
                .setParameter("countryName", value);
        country = (EntityCountry) query.getSingleResult();
        return country;
    }


    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        EntityCountry c = (EntityCountry) value;
        return c.getCountryName();
    }
}
```

I can open a country pages successfully (for example `http://localhost:8080/test/faces/country.xhtml?country=england`), but when I try to post a comment using the `commandButton`, the `setComment` setter is not called and the `comment` variable remains `null`. I tried to set `immediate="true"` on both `inputText` and `commandButton`, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` attribute of `<f:ajax>` defaults to `@this`, the current component. If you want to submit the entire form, then you need `@form` instead. Use this in the `render` as well.

```
<h:commandButton value="Send">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{countryBean2.sendComment}" render="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i tried to submit form without ajax and with immediate="true" attribute. i am using prettyfaces. pretty urls turns ugly when i use commandbutton without ajax and immediate="true" attribute. i think i can overstep with this information. thank you very much.